# Google Sheets Query - transform rows before a query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets table similar to this:

```
| date     | buyer | country | item 1 | item 2 | item 3  | ...
| 2022\1\1 | A.B.  | LAT     | milk   | coffee | sugar   | ...
| 2022\1\2 | C.D.  | GER     | milk   | cocoa  | cookies | ...
```

Is it possible to transform it somehow to a table, that has only one item per row, example:

```
| date     | buyer | country | item    |
| 2022\1\1 | A.B.  | LAT     | milk    |
| 2022\1\1 | A.B.  | LAT     | coffee  |
| 2022\1\1 | A.B.  | LAT     | sugar   |
| 2022\1\2 | C.D.  | GER     | milk    |
| 2022\1\2 | C.D.  | GER     | cocoa   |
| 2022\1\2 | C.D.  | GER     | cookies |
```

So that I can afterward query it for what was sold when and where.
In a regular DB, I would have two (or 3) tables with 1-N relations doing a simple join/joins, but I cannot figure out how to do it in google sheets. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this simple [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function formula in `H2`.

```
=QUERY({A2:C,D2:D;A2:C,E2:E;A2:C,F2:F}, " Select * Where Col1 is not null ")
```

And this in `H1`.

```
=ArrayFormula({A1:C1,"Items"})
```

Like this, take a look at the [spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F9qfi2xFh6xYdaAQdpcwdiDpjpKhAgTfDHMpDPdLytU/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Formula**    `=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A&"|"&B2:B&"|"&C2:C&"|"&D2:F,A2:A<>"")),"|"))`

**Note:** You only need to change the range when there are many items

> 3 items => D2:F
>
> 4 items => D2:G
>
> 5 items => D2:H
>
> ...

[image]

**Function References**

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=FILTER({{A2:C;A2:C;A2:C},{D2:D;E2:E;F2:F}},NOT(ISBLANK({A2:A;A2:A;A2:A})))
```

### Explanation

This creates an array where each entry in columns A through C is duplicated three times, once for each entry in columns D through F. The `=FILTER` then returns only rows where column A is not empty.

Note that this is not an easily scalable function if you have a large number of different `item` columns to parse.

Functions used:

- [=FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [=NOT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305?hl=en)
- [=ISBLANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative. You can also utilize AppScript to do so. I developed a project that you can review with access to a Sheet and access "Extensions" and open the AppScript Project.

- [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iIntJ2eqMte_VY9DFzpuxkOiYzcAgSfXy6qbRPq79tg/edit#gid=0)

You just need to run the function. It was based on a Macro from one of my Excel projects. Sample below.

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */



function concatenarItems() {

  // Declarando las variables necesarias
  var LastColumn = 0;
  var LastRow = 0;
  var i = 0;  // rows
  var j = 0;  //gathering data
  var iT = 0;
  var jT = 0;
  var jR = 0;        // extra items
  var dte = '';      // Date
  var buyer = '';    // buyer
  var country = '';  // country
  var items;         // row of items
  // finding the last 
  LastColumn =
      6;  // columns
  var dummy_RowIndex = countCells(getActiveSheetRows());
  LastRow = convertToInteger(getRowIndex(makeIterableRangeList(
      getLastCellInRange(getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), dummy_RowIndex, 1), xlUp))));
  // original table 
  i = 1;
  j = 1;
  // Ubicacion de la nueva tabla
  iT = 2;  // row
  jT = 8;  // Column
  while (_vba_operator_lt(i, LastRow)) {
    // Save row
    var dummy_RowIndex_2 = _vba_operator_add(i, 1);
    dte = convertToString(getRangeValue(
        xlRangeValueDefault,
        getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), dummy_RowIndex_2, j).rangeList));
    var dummy_RowIndex_3 = _vba_operator_add(i, 1);
    var dummy_ColumnIndex = _vba_operator_add(j, 1);
    buyer = convertToString(getRangeValue(
        xlRangeValueDefault,
        getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), dummy_RowIndex_3, dummy_ColumnIndex).rangeList));
    var dummy_RowIndex_4 = _vba_operator_add(i, 1);
    var dummy_ColumnIndex_2 = _vba_operator_add(j, 2);
    country = convertToString(getRangeValue(
        xlRangeValueDefault,
        getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), dummy_RowIndex_4, dummy_ColumnIndex_2)
            .rangeList));
    var dummy_RowIndex_5 = _vba_operator_add(i, 1);
    var dummy_ColumnIndex_3 = _vba_operator_add(j, 3);
    items = getRangeValue(
        xlRangeValueDefault,
        getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), dummy_RowIndex_5, dummy_ColumnIndex_3)
            .rangeList);  //save item
    // save row
    setValueForRangeList(
        getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), iT, jT),
        verifyRangeValueType(xlRangeValueDefault, dte));
    // date
    var dummy_ColumnIndex_4 = _vba_operator_add(jT, 1);
    setValueForRangeList(
        getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), iT, dummy_ColumnIndex_4),
        verifyRangeValueType(xlRangeValueDefault, buyer));
    // buyer
    var dummy_ColumnIndex_5 = _vba_operator_add(jT, 2);
    setValueForRangeList(
        getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), iT, dummy_ColumnIndex_5),
        verifyRangeValueType(xlRangeValueDefault, country));
    // country
    var dummy_ColumnIndex_6 = _vba_operator_add(jT, 3);
    setValueForRangeList(
        getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), iT, dummy_ColumnIndex_6),
        verifyRangeValueType(xlRangeValueDefault, items));
    // items
    jR = 4;  // count reset
    // Rest of items.
    while (_vba_operator_lt(jR, _vba_operator_add(LastColumn, 1))) {
      var dummy_RowIndex_6 = _vba_operator_add(i, 1);
      items = defaultRangeGetter(getCells(
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), dummy_RowIndex_6,
          jR));  // rewrite item
      setValueForRangeList(
          getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), iT, jT),
          verifyRangeValueType(xlRangeValueDefault, dte));
      var dummy_ColumnIndex_7 = _vba_operator_add(jT, 1);
      setValueForRangeList(
          getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), iT, dummy_ColumnIndex_7),
          verifyRangeValueType(xlRangeValueDefault, buyer));
      var dummy_ColumnIndex_8 = _vba_operator_add(jT, 2);
      setValueForRangeList(
          getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), iT, dummy_ColumnIndex_8),
          verifyRangeValueType(xlRangeValueDefault, country));
      var dummy_ColumnIndex_9 = _vba_operator_add(jT, 3);
      setValueForRangeList(
          getCells(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), iT, dummy_ColumnIndex_9),
          verifyRangeValueType(xlRangeValueDefault, items));
      iT = _vba_operator_add(iT, 1);
      jR = _vba_operator_add(jR, 1);
    }
    i = _vba_operator_add(i, 1);  
  }
}
```